# fire a button click event using java script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How would i fire a button click event after a user pressed the OK button in a **OK cancel pop up window**?? **(like return confrim)** i used the following code to call the btnCommitSaving click event if the user pressed OK but i doesnt work. is there something wrong with the code?

```
 ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
 csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "__Mensagem", "if (confirm('" + "Proceed" + "')){  var button = document.getElementByID(btnCommitSaving);button.click();}", true);
```

please help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client Script Manager not firing button click event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018460/client-script-manager-not-firing-button-click-event)

Comment: syntax error of jquery..check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did this earlier today. Easiest way is to use `__doPostBack` from javascript:

```
// Assume myButton is an <asp:Button> (or anything) previously defined
// that has an OnClick event registered in the code behind
var uniqueID = '<%= myButton.UniqueID %>';
var additionalData = '';
__doPostBack(uniqueID, arguments);
```

The arguments come back in `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` if you're interested in those. The tricky thing is to use `UniqueID` instead of `ClientID` with the `__doPostBack`. A lot of sites tell you to use `ClientID`, this will do the postback, but won't route into the event handler.

**Edit**

Another opition is to set `OnClientClick` on the button to a javascript function that returns true/false:

```
function someJSFunction()
{
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');
}

<asp:Button OnClientClick='return someJSFunction();' OnClick='CodeBehindMethod' />
```

This way, the codebehind method will only fire if the JS function returns true.

Comment: Can you tell me how to implement it in my code? because my problem is if a user pressed OK in a OK-Cancel Button he will perform the **buttonclick** if Cancel then Do nothing.

Comment: or if applicable if OK was pressed do a method.

Comment: I provided you with 2 different approaches that should work (didnt test it to be sure...). I typically don't register JS functions from the code behind, that gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

it would be helpful to you

```
                    <div class="loginBox">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function Confirm() {
                            var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
                            confirm_value.type = "hidden";
                            confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
                            if (confirm("Are you sure Want to submit all Budgeted Requirement ?")) {
                                confirm_value.value = "Yes";
                            } else {
                                confirm_value.value = "No";
                            }
                            document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
                        }
                    </script>
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick = "Confirm();" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click" />
                    </div>


protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (grdBudgetMgr.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (confirmValue == "Yes")
        {

            ClsBudgetManager objBudgetManager = new ClsBudgetManager();
            objBudgetManager.UpdateBudgetSentAllStatus(Convert.ToInt32(hdnClientId.Value), Convert.ToInt32(ddlBudgetlist.SelectedValue), true);
            GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: ohw im sorry wrong peopel to comment im just starting to try your code.

Comment: yes it is working but in your code, the confirmation appears after the click, what i intented to do is in the middle of the flow of the program (not after a click lets say after an **iF**) it would perform a method/button click after a user has clicked OK and do nothing if no.

Comment: ya i understand your problem but its alternative way which i used. i don't know how client side method call server side if you  get please let me know also .if this is helpful to you please vote my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');" OnClick="btnCommitSaving_Click" />
```

or

```
ClientScriptManager csm = Page.ClientScript;
csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "__Mensagem", "if (confirm('Proceed?')){$('#" + btnCommitSaving.ClientID + "').click();}", true);
```

Comment: still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csm.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "__Mensagem", "if (confirm('Proceed')){  var button = document.getElementByID('btnCommitSaving');button.click();}", true);
```

Comment: /Vash nothing happens still just passes through it,

Comment: im sorry but i do not know because im new in programmin can you tell me how to look for the error

Answer (score 0):

I have found problem in your code.
first of all **document.getElementById** is wrong in your code. *JavaScript* is case sensitive.

second problem is that your code is finding button *btnCommitSaving* before it gets rendered completely on page. so **var button = document.getElementById('btnCommitSaving')** is returning null and **button.click()** event is not executing.

Try it to call by some other way when all *HTML Page* got rendered.